# ESP8266 blink not building to esp-01

Tags: esp8266

I am trying the esp8266 esp-01, and did all it asked on the arduino IDE side, but i am having problems compiling and building the blink example into the board

Using: FT232RL usb-ttl in the 3.3v configuration, two 1.6v (new) batteries to power the esp, and all the conections as indicated here (not using the led though).

when I hit (go) it compiles, but as it transfers both boards blink sincronously and I recive the following errors:

O sketch usa 219.479 bytes (50%) de espaço de armazenamento para programas. O máximo são 434.160 bytes. Variáveis globais usam 31.172 bytes (38%) de memória dinâmica, deixando 50.748 bytes para variáveis locais. O máximo são 81.920 bytes.

error: failed reading byte warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data error: failed reading byte warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data error: failed reading byte warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data error: failed reading byte warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data error: failed reading byte warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data error: failed reading byte warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data error: failed reading byte warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data error: failed reading byte warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data error: failed reading byte warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data warning: espcomm_sync failed error: espcomm_open failed error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

I looks to me as a newbie that its trying to establish a link and failing... what could it be?

the configurations are default, programmer is "AVRISP MKII"

Answer (score 1):

You did not put ESP8266 into programing mode.

the easiest way to do so is to make your own programing board, something like [shown here](http://www.whatimade.today/esp8266-easiest-way-to-program-so-far/). Go down to middle of the document to title "Writing a program to the ESP8266" where you will see a schematic of simple programing board. You will need two switches and a 10k resistor.

The voltage regulator can be omitted if you are powering it by 3.3v power. Also its a good idea to put a small capacitor (100uf) between vcc and ground to stabilize any drops in voltage which is primary cause of esp8266 rebooting it self.